Redirecting to login page of Amazon opensearch with VPC enabled(fine grained with master user) even after giving correct credentials
I have created amazon opensearch domain with vpc enabled. I am using fine grained access with master user/password.
To access it outside vpc I have used nginx proxy_pass as k8s deployment and service. I am able to see login page (redirection is happening) but after giving credentials, again redirecting it to login page.
upon debugging using webpage what i have found it.. ( using F12 network tab ) below are giving 401 unauthorized. _dashboards/api/ism/apiCaller Request Method: POST Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
_dashboards/api/v1/multitenancy/tenant Request Method: GET Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
_dashboards/api/v1/restapiinfo Request Method: GET Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
_dashboards/api/v1/configuration/account Request Method: GET Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
_dashboards/api/v1/auth/dashboardsinfo Request Method: GET Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
dashboards/api/dataconnections Request Method: GET Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
dashboards/api/v1/configuration/account Request Method: GET Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
dashboards/api/v1/multitenancy/tenant Request Method: GET Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
I am able to access VPC endpoints with same credentials successfully. Do i need to any extra permissions or some policy to make it work.
Please help for the above. I am stuck from past one week.
I am able to access VPC endpoints with same credentials successfully. but login to dashboard is redirecting to same

We met the same issue when the nginx proxy was used to the aws opensearch under the VPC.
After adding the proxy_cookie_domain to nginx config, it works well. Here are the details of nginx config.
server
{
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name $host;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert.key;

  ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  set $es_endpoint https://[vpc endpoint].[region].es.amazonaws.com;

  location /_dashboards {
    proxy_pass https://[vpc endpoint].[region].es.amazonaws.com/_dashboards;
    proxy_cookie_domain $es_endpoint $host;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://[vpc endpoint].[region].es.amazonaws.com;
    proxy_cookie_domain $es_endpoint $host;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
  }
}

